# Error Running Holoview Example of Chord Diagram

Tags: python, numpy, holoviews, chord-diagram

I am learning HoloViews currently and wanted to reproduce the Chord-Example from the Homepage:

http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/route_chord.html

I copied the lines per line into my jupyter-nb and get always an error this line:

```
chord = hv.Chord((route_counts, nodes), ['SourceID', 'DestinationID'], ['Stops'])
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    116     try:
--> 117         num = operator.index(num)
    118     except TypeError:

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b727deae3660> in <module>
----> 1 chord = hv.Chord((route_counts, nodes), ['SourceID', 'DestinationID'], ['Stops'])
      2 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\element\graphs.py in __init__(self, data, kdims, vdims, compute, **params)
    768         if compute:
    769             self._nodes = nodes
--> 770             chord = layout_chords(self)
    771             self._nodes = chord.nodes
    772             self._edgepaths = chord.edgepaths

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\param\parameterized.py in __new__(class_, *args, **params)
   2810         inst = class_.instance()
   2811         inst.param._set_name(class_.__name__)
-> 2812         return inst.__call__(*args,**params)
   2813 
   2814     def __call__(self,*args,**kw):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in __call__(self, element, **kwargs)
    162         elif 'streams' not in kwargs:
    163             kwargs['streams'] = self.p.streams
--> 164         return element.apply(self, **kwargs)
    165 
    166 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\accessors.py in __call__(self, function, streams, link_inputs, dynamic, **kwargs)
    108             if hasattr(function, 'dynamic'):
    109                 inner_kwargs['dynamic'] = False
--> 110             return function(self._obj, **inner_kwargs)
    111         elif self._obj._deep_indexable:
    112             mapped = []

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in __call__(self, element, **kwargs)
    159                                       for k, el in element.items()])
    160             elif isinstance(element, ViewableElement):
--> 161                 return self._apply(element)
    162         elif 'streams' not in kwargs:
    163             kwargs['streams'] = self.p.streams

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in _apply(self, element, key)
    119         for hook in self._preprocess_hooks:
    120             kwargs.update(hook(self, element))
--> 121         ret = self._process(element, key)
    122         for hook in self._postprocess_hooks:
    123             ret = hook(self, ret, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\element\graphs.py in _process(self, element, key)
    677             n_conn = weights_of_areas[i]
    678             p0, p1 = points[i], points[i+1]
--> 679             angles = np.linspace(p0, p1, n_conn)
    680             coords = list(zip(np.cos(angles), np.sin(angles)))
    681             all_areas.append(coords)

<__array_function__ internals> in linspace(*args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    119         raise TypeError(
    120             "object of type {} cannot be safely interpreted as an integer."
--> 121                 .format(type(num)))
    122 
    123     if num < 0:

TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Best

As requested:

```
print((type(route_counts), type(nodes)))
print((route_counts.dtypes))

(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'holoviews.core.data.Dataset'>)
SourceID         int64
DestinationID    int64
Stops            int64
dtype: object
```

Packages and versions:

```
holoviews                 1.12.7                     py_0    pyviz
pandas                    1.0.0            py37h47e9c7a_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h93ca92e_0
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0
```

Tried the downloaded notebook and got the same error message.

Comment: have you checked `type(route_counts)` and `type(nodes)`?

Comment: with me those line works. Are you using Holoviews 1.12.7? And which version of bokeh, numpy, pandas? Can you add that to the question? If you are using older versions, then consider updating packages.

Comment: Have you tried the "Download this notebook from GitHub" link on that page? That way you can be sure there are no subtle errors or omissions.  Actually, to be sure the code you are running matches the HoloViews version you have downloaded, you can get all the notebooks with `holoviews --install-examples ; cd holoviews-examples`.

Comment: added the requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. There's a problem handling numpy 1.18.1. 

I tried this with numpy 1.17.4 and had no problem.
When I upgraded to 1.18.1 I also got this error.

As you can see in your error message, the error is caused by this line in holoviews:

```
angles = np.linspace(p0, p1, n_conn)
```

Created an issue:
https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4223

Turns out, there was already an issue:
https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4209